# Background Work: Use single background thread or launch one thread per loop?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm doing some video analysis in python and I want to use multithreading to speed up my analysis.
Without multithreading, my program can be written in the following way

```
for frame in video:
    res1 = run_costly_function1(frame, res_prev)
    res2 = run_costly_function2(frame, res_prev)
    res_prev = run_function2(res1, res2)
```

However, the function `run_costly_function1` and `run_costly_function2` do not depend on each other and can thus be run in parallel. I'm also using OpenCV functions heavily, which release the global interpreter lock and I thus thought multithreading should be doable.

I can think of two different ways of solving this:

1. Launching a new thread every iteration whose task it is to calculate `run_costly_function2`:

   ```
   for frame in video:
       background_worker = Thread(target=run_costly_function2, args=(frame, res_rev))
       background_worker.start()
       res1 = run_costly_function1(frame, res_rev)
       res2 = background_worker.join()
       res_prev = run_function2(res1, res2)
   ```
2. Having a single background thread and use a queue to communicate with it:

   ```
   q = queue.Queue()
   background_worker = Thread(target=background_worker_func, args=(q,))
   background_worker.start()

   for frame in video:
       q.put((frame, res_prev))
       res1 = run_costly_function1(frame, res_prev)            
       res2 = q.get()
       res_prev = run_function2(res1, res2)
   ```

My question is which of these methods is better? Maybe there even is a third alternative that I overlooked? I'm willing to use additional modules like `futures` if they are useful.

The solution is supposed to scale up to processing ~100 frames per second and I'm afraid that creating a 100 threads per second (in method 1) is costly. However, communicating using a queue (in method 2) seems more complicated to implement and thus more error-prone.

Comment: queue is better because of overhead thread make and switch costs. Is one frame related to another in your algorithm? If not there are another way to split work by frames.

Comment: The frames are related to one another. I thought about processing frames independently, but this is not possible. In essence, the `run_costly_function`s take input from the previous frame and I like to keep it this way. I'll update the question, too.

Comment: The fastest way depends on how much cores in your cpu, how long costly functions works.  possible you have to split both havy functions to separate thread and sync in third thread. Also, in your case queue never have more than one element, because of that and hi frequency of switching you probably should use a more faster synchronization primitives

Comment: Thanks for these hints, gabba. Could you point me to "faster synchronization primitives"? I implemented a solution based on Queues yesterday, but a queue is indeed not really needed, since it contains at most one item, as you already pointed out. I have enough cores (~32 on my testing machine).

Comment: To utilize so much cores you need to remove dependencies between steps and make conveyor. 
Can you split big bunch of frames to groups and process each group by one core?

Comment: Syncronization primitives https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#

Comment: I now use `threading.Event` to synchronize the different threads. I now see satisfactory performance and will probably leave it at that. Thanks for the link on the synchronization primitives! I certainly need to learn more until I feel comfortable with multithreading... If you wanna post an answer proposing alternative synchronization primitives with the link, I'd accept it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making thread is heavy operation, so create as many threads as cores you have and can effectively utilize. I think that in your case, without changing the algorithms, the maximum number of threads is 3.

To reduce switching costs do not move light operations to the separate threads.
Use fastest sync primetives appropriate for the particular case. Somtimes beter solution is not suspend thread and wait in loop.

Queues is good for processing bunches of independent data, in case independent data work can easily be splited with multiple workers. After processing result can passed to the next queue and so on.